# Selecting monthly counts with zero occurrences

Tags: mysql, select, count, union

my problem is in selecting counts of records from database based on year and month of their creatin. I have this MySQL query:

```
SELECT year, m, month, COUNT(bans.ban_id) AS total
FROM (
    SELECT year, m, month
    FROM
    (SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) year UNION ALL SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-1) years,
    (
        SELECT 1 m, 'Jan' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 2 m, 'Feb' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 3 m, 'Mar' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 4 m, 'Apr' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 5 m, 'May' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 6 m, 'Jun' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 7 m, 'Jul' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 8 m, 'Aug' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 9 m, 'Sep' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 10 m, 'Oct' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 11 m, 'Nov' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 12 m, 'Dec' month
    ) months
) ym
LEFT JOIN bans
    ON ym.year = YEAR(bans.ban_created_at)
    AND ym.m = MONTH(bans.ban_created_at)
WHERE
    (year=YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m<=MONTH(CURDATE()))
    OR
    (year<YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m>MONTH(CURDATE()))
    AND
    (ban_banlist_id = 13)
GROUP BY year, m
```

It is working almost properly, but - problem is that the query returns only values with valid count of records - e.g. **when there is no record in the month, it is not returned**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the condition on the right table (bans) is on the WHERE clause, so it's apply on the result, with the effect that only month with occurences will be selected. Put it on the ON clause of the LEFT JOIN clause, like this:

```sql
SELECT year, m, month, COUNT(bans.ban_id) AS total
FROM (
    SELECT year, m, month
    FROM
    (SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) year UNION ALL SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-1) years,
    (
        SELECT 1 m, 'Jan' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 2 m, 'Feb' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 3 m, 'Mar' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 4 m, 'Apr' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 5 m, 'May' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 6 m, 'Jun' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 7 m, 'Jul' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 8 m, 'Aug' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 9 m, 'Sep' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 10 m, 'Oct' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 11 m, 'Nov' month
        UNION ALL SELECT 12 m, 'Dec' month
    ) months
) ym
LEFT JOIN bans
    ON ym.year = YEAR(bans.ban_created_at)
    AND ym.m = MONTH(bans.ban_created_at)
    AND ban_banlist_id = 13
WHERE
    (year=YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m<=MONTH(CURDATE()))
    OR
    (year<YEAR(CURDATE()) AND m>MONTH(CURDATE()))
GROUP BY year, m
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot. :) Could you briefly explain why is that?

Comment: If you a add a condition on where clause on the right table of a left join (here bans), it will only select the lines where there are some bans (here where id = 13), so at the end, you will only have results with bans where id =13, and nothing if there is no occurence. So for that, if there is a condition on the right table (bans), put it in the ON clause.

Comment: Got that! Thank you! ^^